# How to implement Google Play Promo Code redeem?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, android-billing

To implement promo codes I've made the following steps:

1. In Google Play Console>User Acquisition>Promotions I've added the promotion
2. Inside the app I've used this to redirect user to the Redeem page on Google Play:

   ```
          try {
               final Uri redeemUri = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/redeem");
               final Intent redeemIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, redeemUri);
               activity.startActivity(redeemIntent);
           } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
               // Play Store app is not installed
           }
   ```

Everything works up to a point when I actually click redeem. It detects the IAP I'm about to purchase for free, but it gives me the following error:

[image: BX--INV error]

Please, help

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/2149922?hl=en), Google has responded to this error code with "This is an emerging issue that we are aware of. Our engineers are working on a resolution."

It seems to be an issue with redeeming many digital copies of movies, and sometimes ebooks. So it may be a more general problem with their system for redeeming outside content.

But given that was 3 days ago and this post is 6 months old, I'm not particularly hopeful.